# kivymd OneLineIconListItem change to new screen when you click

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i need to change to new screen when i click on OneLineIconListItem pls help me

MDNavigationDrawer:
id:nav_drawer
BoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'
spancing: '8dp'
padding: '8dp'
Image:
source: 'image.png'

```
            ScrollView:                    
                MDList:
                    
                    
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Home"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon : 'home-circle'
                        
                            
                          
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Contact Us Here"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon : 'email'
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Help"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon : 'help-circle'
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Setting"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon : 'cog'
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Search"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon : 'magnify'
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The `OneLineIconListItem` implements `ButtonBehavior`, so you can just add `on_release:` or `on_press:` to run anything you want when it is clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView:
MDList:

```
    OneLineIconListItem:
        text: "Home"
        IconLeftWidget:
            icon : 'home-circle'
        on_press:root.funation name()

    OneLineIconListItem:
        text: "Contact Us Here"
        IconLeftWidget:
            icon : 'email'
        on_press:root.function name()

    OneLineIconListItem:
        text: "Help"
        IconLeftWidget:
            icon : 'help-circle'
        on_press:root.function name()

    OneLineIconListItem:
        text: "Setting"
        IconLeftWidget:
            icon : 'cog'
        on_press:root.function name()

    OneLineIconListItem:
        text: "Search"
        IconLeftWidget:
            icon : 'magnify'
        on_press:root.function name()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).